official highcharts json schema / type definition?
Is there an official JSON schema / type definition for the highcharts library?
We would like to generate our charts server side (Java) and then send the resulting JSON to the client. It would be great that we can generate a (Java class) model which can build the JSON, and is compiler checkable.

Here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/ you can find a visual reprezentation of Highcharts API.
You can download the API from the same page in ZIP or JSON format.
Here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tree.json is the direct link to the JSON version. You can get the JSON and map it according to your requirements.
